# Installing PHP 5.4.11 on CentOS 6.3

Tags: php, centos, yum

I have `PHP 5.3.3` on my `CentOs 6.3` server, Since this version of `PHP` is vulnerable now trying to upgrade to `PHP 5.4.11` but the default repository of `CentOs` does not have `PHP > 5.3.3` so `yum` can not detect the newer version.

I then installed `remi` repository on my server

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

These command installed repository successfully

Now the command to upgrade PHP

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-test update httpd mysql mysql-server php php-common
```

But it fails with below error message

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again
```

If i try `yum info php` the same error message

Basically after installing these repositories `yum` is not working, but yum was working earlier.

If I remove these repository and try `yum` it works without any error.

How can I have `PHP` upgraded to `PHP 5.4.11` version?

**EDIT**
As @Michael Suggests I ran

```
yum clean all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Cleaning repos: base epel extras updates
Cleaning up Everything
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
`[root@www ~]# yum --obsoletes update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again
```

Still the same error

**EDIT 2**

Content of `epel.repo`

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch/debug
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/SRPMS
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1
```

Internet connection is working well, I checked with

```
 wget http://google.com
```

**EDIT 3**

As @Michael Suggests I ran

`URLGRABBER_DEBUG=1 yum check-update`
And It ended up with the following error

```
 Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)
2013-02-24 20:31:45,730 exception: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 77 - "Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)"
INFO:urlgrabber:exception: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 77 - "Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)"
2013-02-24 20:31:46,051 retrycode (14) not in list [-1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], re-raising
INFO:urlgrabber:retrycode (14) not in list [-1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7], re-raising
Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again
```

So, the actual issue is with SSL certificate but why it is complaining about SSL certificate however it is valid one

Comment: Does yum update not work?

Comment: Have you tried downloading and installing/compiling from source?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the remi yum package is called php54 or something simular. Please try run a #yum search php and look for the php package names.

Comment: @Danie: The thing is after installing remi package, yum is not working

Comment: Please run: `URLGRABBER_DEBUG=1 yum check-update`

Comment: @MichaelHampton: Thanks man, It is SSL certificate which is preventing yum but why? SSL certificate is valid. See my edit

Comment: I updated my answer based on the information you provided.

Comment: SSL will fail for this PyCurl library unless the date & time of the client and server are similar. In my case, my client was way off. I updated the date/time and configured ntp, then re-tried with success! Crypto can be picky about time synchronization. Thanks for the hint aobut URLGRABBER_DEBUG and SSL cert errors, helped me check my system time problem and fix yum for this epel repository ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After adding new repositories, clear your yum cache and update your system before attempting to install any more packages.

```
yum clean all
yum --obsoletes update
```

---

Based on your updated information, it appears your local CA certificates have been corrupted or removed. Try reinstalling them:

```
yum reinstall ca-certificates
```

Comment: still does not work same error. `yum clean all`
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Cleaning repos: base epel extras updates
Cleaning up Everything
Cleaning up list of fastest mirrors
`[root@www ~]# yum --obsoletes update`
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Determining fastest mirrors
Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again

Comment: Check the contents of `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` and make sure you actually have Internet connectivity.

Comment: Michael, I posted content of `epel.repo` and checked the internet connection, internet connections is working.

Comment: I have godaddy SSL certificate. After running this command do I have to reinstall the godaddy certificate or does this automatically re install my godaddy certificate. Please help

Comment: Yes, `yum reinstall ca-certificates` did it

Comment: my bad, I can't upvote, will come back when get more reputation

Answer (score 0):

vi epel.repo

changed https in

mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch to
mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch

WORKED!

Comment: I keep seeing this suggestion everywhere but disabling https does not seem to be the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

solution to update old versions:

```
rpm -e epel-release
yum clean all
yum -y --obsoletes update --skip-broken
yum reinstall ca-certificates
yum -y update --skip-broken
yum -y install epel-release
```